# TF259035: Team Foundation Server placed the environment in the failed state

Tags: tfs

Yesterday, we tried to restore a snapshot of a SCVMM Env. But it is failed because the TFS lost connection to SCVMM.
And we got the following error message

> Environment message: Type=Error; Message=TF259035: Team Foundation
>   Server placed the environment in the failed state. A failed state
>   indicates that one or more virtual machines are unusable. Contact your
>   system administrator, and ask them to bring the affected virtual
>   machines into a usable state;
>
> Machine messages:
>
> Machine name: machine06
>
> Machine message: Type=Error; Message= TF260110: Team Foundation Server
>   could not get details of the virtual machine because of some transient
>   problem and placed the virtual machine in Unknown state. As soon the
>   details are available from System Center Virtual Machine Manager
>   server, Team Foundation Server will update the state of virtual
>   machine.   Additional information: The name of the virtual machine in
>   System Center Virtual Machine Manager is machine06.;
>
> Machine name: machine07
>
> Machine message: Type=Error; Message= TF260110: Team Foundation Server
>   could not get details of the virtual machine because of some transient
>   problem and placed the virtual machine in Unknown state. As soon the
>   details are available from System Center Virtual Machine Manager
>   server, Team Foundation Server will update the state of virtual
>   machine.   Additional information: The name of the virtual machine in
>   System Center Virtual Machine Manager is machine07.;
>
> ---
>
> Environment message: Type=Error; Message=TF259175: Team Foundation Server failed
>   to restore the following environment to snapshot: Env0607 to
>   EnvReady0. The restore operation failed on one or more virtual
>   machines, and as a result the root of the environment snapshot tree
>   has been reset. To recover from this condition, attempt to restore the
>   environment again either to the same or a different snapshot.;
>
> Machine messages:
>
> Machine name: machine06
>
> Machine message: Type=Error; Message=TF260078: Team Foundation Server
>   could not connect to the System Center Virtual Machine Manager Server:
>   *scvmm server ip*. More information for administrator: TF260038: Team Foundation Server is initializing connection to the System Center
>   Virtual Machine Manager: *scvmm server ip*. Please try the operation
>   after some time.;
>
> Machine name: machine07
>
> Machine message: Type=Error; Message=TF260078: Team Foundation Server
>   could not connect to the System Center Virtual Machine Manager Server:
>   *scvmm server ip*. More information for administrator: TF260038: Team Foundation Server is initializing connection to the System Center
>   Virtual Machine Manager: *scvmm server ip*. Please try the operation
>   after some time.;

We have tried to restart the VMs from SCVMM but the issue is still.
Also from the Env, we can't do any snapshot operations and power operations including shutdown.

Comment: Have you verified if the tfs->scvmm server connection is working fine? You can do this by heading to the tfs server opening up TfsMgmt.exe and going to the lab node and clicking verify on the scvmm server config

Comment: Thanks Allen. Yes it is caused by the connection lost from TFS to Scvmm.

Comment: Today we find our SC is offline and all lab environments are set as failed status by TFS.
And when the SCVMM is started, for about 4hrs, the lab Envs are still in failed status.

We have checked: 
1. TFS can connect to SCVMM 2. Just refresh Envs in test manager can't fix the status issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, the root cause is that
 1.SQL server uses too high memory on TFS server (because the "lock pages in memory" feature is enable and sql max memory is set 6G)
 2.There is about more than 98% memory in use on tfs server
 3.So there no memory left for other tasks on TFS server.   (TFS App tire is combined with db tire)

Solution:
1.Limit Sql server max memory to 4G (server has 8G)
2.Restart TFS
3.Restart each failed environments